# The two terms of Boltzmann machine update rule

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

According to [this document](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/absps/guideTR.pdf).
The update rule for a restricted Boltzmann machine comes from the following partial derivative for gradient ascent:

$$\frac{\partial \log p(V)}{\partial w_{ij}} = \langle v_i h_j \rangle_{\text{data}} - \langle v_i h_j \rangle_{\text{model}}$$

What do these two terms on the right-hand side mean? Especially the latter one?

Comment: Hi, welcome. Did you notice this line in the document _"...where  the  angle  brackets are used  to denote expectations under the distribution specified by the subscript that follows"_?

Comment: According to Hinton's original paper: https://enterrasolutions.com/media/docs/2013/08/cogscibm.pdf, $<v_ih_j>_{model}$ is the "mean correlation" in the negative phase (no clamping) after $v_i$ and $h_j$ are determined by Gibbs sampling? and $<v_ih_j>_{data}$ is the "mean correlation" in the postive phase (clamped visible states) with $h_j$ determined by Gibbs sampling? Not sure about this...

Comment: correct me if I am wrong: the mean correlation doesn't need Gibbs sampling since it involves a sum over all possible states?

Comment: I think the sample average from Gibbs sampling is used to approximate the actual derivative which involves a sum over all possible states. We need to measure the sample average after "equilibrium" is reached?

Comment: First, the notation $\langle X \, Y \rangle_{\text{data}}$ to denote $E_{\text{data}}(X \, Y)$ is non-standard in statistics and probability. But, we should not be pedantic about it, as long as it is properly defined somewhere prior in the document. The subscripts "$\text{data}$" and "$\text{model}$" in $E_{\text{data}}(X \, Y)$ and $E_{\text{model}}(X \, Y)$ *are* very hand-wavy. It is impossible to infer the exact meaning from that notation. Again, if properly **defined** somewhere in the document: no problemo – it's efficient shorthand.

Answer (score 0):

Very roughly speaking, the first term decreases the energy of data sampled from the true distribution (pushing up their probability), whereas the second term increases the energy of data sampled from the model, decreasing their probability. As some commentors pointed out, this just falls out of the math when you take the gradient of the log likelihood.

Regarding the unclear notation: For the first term, $v$ is distributed according to the training data, and $h ~\sim p(h|v;\theta)$ which is tractable. For the second term, $v, h \sim p(v,h;\theta)$, where $p(v,h;\theta)$ is the (intractable) distribution defined by the model. Sampling is usually done using block gibbs sampling.